# Why is .show() not fired after .slideUp()?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm gracefully trying to close a file list div after upload.

```
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {
    jQuery('#filelist').delay(500).slideUp('slow').promise().done(function(){
        jQuery('#filelist .file_name').remove();
    }).show();
});
```

`.slideUp()` adds the style `style="display: none;"` to my div. I'm trying to remove this by calling `.show()` after `.slideUp()` has fired. But it seems a) I don't quite understnd how jQuery works and b) placed the `.show()` in the wrong place.

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example let's say you have a `display:none;` element `.hidden`:

```
$('.hidden').fadeTo(3000, 1).hide(); // will never fade
$('.hidden').hide().fadeTo(3000, 1); // will fade !
```

```
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {
    jQuery('#filelist').delay(500).slideUp('slow').promise().done(function(){
        jQuery('#filelist .file_name').remove();
        jQuery('#filelist').show(); // PUT INSIDE CALLBACK
    });
});
```

Comment: ah, stupid! (sometimes one don't see the  obvious) Thanks :-)